# nodejs multiple debugger clients

Tags: node.js, debugging

I have three nodejs applications running successfully simultaneously, each interacting with others. But when I try to debug all the three of them using

node --debug=[port_value] [file], with different debugger port for each app

I am unable to debug all of them at the same time. I am only able to debug one at a time. Is there a way I can debug multiple nodejs apps at the same time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think using single debugger process to debug multiple processes is supported by debugger and is not a good idea(because debugger does not provide any way to let you switch between debugged processes and the output will be mixed).

For me in your situation, i will start multiple debugger to debug corresponding process.

```
node --debug-brk=65001 a.js
node --debug-brk=65002 b.js

node debug localhost:65001
node debug localhost:65002
```